# Setting up php sites on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, yii

I am trying to set up the nginx server to run a Yii application. I have created a bootsrap yii application using the yiic command and the folder is currently present in /usr/share/nginx/www. The folder is called mysite. I have managed to get this running with the following config in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
  # You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    set $host_path "/usr/share/nginx/";
    access_log  /usr/share/nginx/www/log/access.log;

    server_name  diabcalc;
    root   $host_path/www;
    set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
    }

    #avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files by yii
    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

        #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
        set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
            set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

        #PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED can be omitted, but RFC 3875 specifies them for CGI
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}

server {
       listen 80;
       server_name phpmyadmin;
       root /usr/share/nginx/www/;

       index index.php index.html;
       location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }
       location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }
       # Make sure files with the following extensions do not get loaded by nginx because nginx would display the source code, and these files can contain PASSWORDS!
        location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
                deny all;
        }
       # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
       location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
       }
       location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
       }
       location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       }
}

# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
#   ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

I have now copied phpmyadmin to the very same folder under which the application resides, ie, /usr/share/nginx/www. So the two folders mysite and phpadmin are present within the above folder. But I cannot get phpadmin to be displayed and I am not sure how to set this up in the nginx config. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

nginx won't handle PHP by itself. You need something to proxy the PHP requests to - PHP-FPM or Apache are common.

Comment: I have set up php-fpm. As mentioned I am able to see the yii site hosted on nginx, at localhost/mysite, but when i try to access localhost/phpmyadmin i get 403 forbidden response. I thought it might be something to do with my config ?

Comment: Apologies for this, I just figured it out. The permissions on the directory were incorrrect. I shall upvote your answer as you do make a valid point! Cheers mate